# OpenGL only most recent vertex draw displayed

Tags: c++, opengl

New to OpenGL, tried to draw 2 rectangles separately using a rectangle draw function.  Using openGL 3, GLFW and GLEW.  I made a function called drawBox to draw a rectangle.
My problem here is that if I call it more than once in the main loop, only the last rectangle drawn is displayed.

```
void drawBox(float x, float y, float w, float h, float r, float g, float b) {
GLfloat colours[15], vertices[10] = {
    x, y,
    x, y + h,
    x + w, y + h,
    x + w, y,
    x, y
};
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    colours[3*i] = (GLfloat)r;
    colours[3*i + 1] = (GLfloat)g;
    colours[3*i + 2] = (GLfloat)b;
}
GLuint buff[2];
glGenBuffers(2, buff);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buff[1]); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15*sizeof(GLfloat), colours, GL_STREAM_DRAW); 
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buff[0]); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 10*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW); 
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glUseProgram(defaultShader);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);        
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDeleteBuffers(2, buff);
}
```

What would I need to change to make this function display a rectangle regardless of past draws.  Assume all z-indices are 0 and overlap never happens.  Assume that I may have to make drawCircle calls or drawTriangle or something in between 2 calls to drawBox.

Comment: you shouldn't create and delete the buffers each draw call, just create once and update when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );` only once, before all `draw*()` calls.

Comment: Ah.  Another thing, am I doing this right?  Is this how you would draw rectangles and other shapes?

Comment: Well, the general idea is right. Some tips: you should do `glGenBuffers` and such only at startup, and then just put there new vertices data. Try to prepare all your vertices and colours in one huge array and then do one `glBufferData(); glDrawArrays();` call for every frame. And if only a small fraction of your rectangles is changing from frame to frame, then consider using `glBufferSubData`.